# how can we make touch enable to a camera view?

Tags: iphone

can we do like that a user touch on the camera view and on this touch we can identify touch locations on this view.

i use the uiimagepickercontroller and added it on a button to the current view, after adding how can i identify  the touch on this camera view that pop up after touch on any button.

Thanks
Balraj verma

Comment: the iphone's camera will draw a box and attempt to focus on whatever you touch on the screen when shooting a picture, so this can be done - whether it can be done using the 'public' APIs i do not know

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new 3.1 Camera API's to turn off the camera controls, and then get a view into which you can add you own subview which detects touches anywhere on the screen.